# data.table := in R package vs. unpackaged script

Tags: r, data.table, operators

I'm trying to write a package, `cleanstreets`, with a few functions I've written for myself that use `data.table`.

Using `data.table`'s `:=` operator seems to be throwing an error when I use it within my package function, but if I cut/paste the code into a plain old R script, or even put it in a function I define within the same script, it works fine.

For example, when I run this as a script in R Studio, no errors are thrown until I try to use the function as packaged...

```
rm(list = ls())
library(cleanstreets)
library(data.table)

DumbFunction <- function(char.vector) {
  library(data.table)
  dt <- data.table(original = as.character(char.vector))

  dt[,three := substr(original,1,3),]

  return (dt)
}

test.vec <- c("One Thing","Two Things","Three things")

dt <- data.table(original = test.vec)

dt[,three := substr(original,1,3),] # this doesn't throw an error

dt.from.local.function <- DumbFunction(test.vec)

dt.from.package.function <- DumbPackageFunction(test.vec)
```

Where in the package we have the definition

```
DumbPackageFunction <- function(char.vector) {
  library(data.table)
  print(search())

  dt <- data.table(original = as.character(char.vector))

  dt[,three := substr(original,1,3),]

  return (dt)
}
```

Only that last line throws an error:

```
Error in `:=`(three, substr(original, 1, 3)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":="). 
6.
stop("Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(\":=\").") 
5.
`:=`(three, substr(original, 1, 3)) 
4.
`[.data.frame`(x, i, j) 
3.
`[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(three, substr(original, 1, 3)), ) at DumbPackageFunction.R#5
2.
dt[, `:=`(three, substr(original, 1, 3)), ] at DumbPackageFunction.R#5
1.
DumbPackageFunction(test.vec)
```

I feel like I'm missing something about how namespace works in packages, but I can't tell what, since it seems like `library(data.table)` ought to cover me. My only thought is that because `:=` isn't a function, namespace rules don't work the same way in packages for it (or other operators?)

But when I `print(search())` from within `DumbPackageFunction()`, I see `data.table`:

```
[1] ".GlobalEnv"           "package:data.table"   "package:cleanstreets"
 [4] "tools:rstudio"        "package:stats"        "package:graphics"    
 [7] "package:grDevices"    "package:utils"        "package:datasets"    
[10] "package:methods"      "Autoloads"            "package:base
```

Comment: Don't use `library` inside you package functions. Read [a bit about how to set up package dependencies](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html) and use the Description and Namespace files to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Updating NAMESPACE seems to have had the desired effect.